# Re assigning window root view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my one of the applications I needed to re assign rootview controller,so for that I have done like below,

```
   self.wndow.rootViewController = nil;
   self.window.rootVIewController = navigationController;
```

But now the problem is previously used class objects are not releasing from memory,retain count of living objects goes on increasing while I re assigning new window rootVIewController, and dealloc method of that Class is not called, I checked retain counts with xcode profile instruments..,any one can help me on this?

Comment: @iSpark if you are using ARC don't need to get worry about!

Comment: Is you initial view controller is an instance variable in the app delegate?

Comment: set properties as strong or retain

Comment: I am facing the same issue now ,only in iOS 9.This issue become relevant because my view controller object receiving  notification as many time as its view did loaded.Any fixes..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC, the dealloc methods will not be called when enabled nszobie objects. So disable them.

Go to `product>edit schems> unchek the enable zombie`

To check the retain count, please use this code and verify

```
CFIndex rc = CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)self.wndow.rootViewController);
```

Comment: Are you saying that `dealloc` isn't called under ARC? I don't think that's true.

Answer (score 0):

How about initializing the window and then assign the root viewcontroller. I did this in one of my previous app without any issues.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't reassign the rootViewController if I could avoid it, I would create my own simple UIViewController subclass to act as a container ViewController and then let it perform the switching between sub viewControllers there are method to help you do this. Alternatively you could use UITabBarController and hide the tab bar.